# Diffeomorphisms of a surface in terms of generators.

Tags: differential-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I am interesting in a presentation of a diffeomorphisms in terms of generators. Is it possible to obtain such presentation in some cases, depending on a genus of a surface or a type of diffeomorphism (i.e if it is periodic)?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  Do you mean a presentation of the group of diffeomorphisms?  Or something else?

Comment: Of course I mean generators of homeotopy group.

Comment: This is still not clear.  Are you asking for an example of a surface with explicit generators and relations for the group of diffeomorphisms of the surface?  Or, as your comment seems to indicate, are you asking for an example of a surface $S$ with presentations of the higher homotopy groups $\pi_n(S)$?  Diffeomorphisms up to homotopy (i.e. the mapping class group)?  There are too many possible interpretations for this question.  You are more likely to get a good response if you make it clear exactly what you are after.

Comment: "a presentation of a diffeomorphisms" ? $\:$

Comment: From Andrew's comment to Igor's question below, it looks to me like the question should be something like this: given a particular element of the mapping class group, say the mapping class of a homeomorphism or diffeomorphism expressed in some concrete manner, is there a procedure which will produce a word in the standard generators of the mapping class group which represents the given mapping class? This is still not a very good question because it does not specify concretely how the mapping class is given.

Comment: @Lee actually, there are two natural ways: one: the homeo is given as a simplicial map. In the other we are given an automorphosm of the fundamental group.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is: can you present the homeotopy group in terms of generators and relations, the answer is "yes", following the work of Hatcher-Thurston, Wajnryb, and most recently M. Korkmaz, who gives a relatively civilized presentation. If you mean: given a homeomorphism, can you express its isotopy class in terms of the generators, I assume that the answer is yes, but it obviously depends on how the homeomorphism is given. For related work, see 
Brinkmann, Peter(1-UT)
An implementation of the Bestvina-Handel algorithm for surface homeomorphisms. (English summary) 
Experiment. Math. 9 (2000), no. 2, 235–240.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will comment your answer and upper questions here. I am considering a particular diffeomorphism (up to isotopy to identity) of a surface F given by a function f: F --> F. Can I write down a presentation of this f in terms of Dehn twists? For example, given an involution x |--> -x,can this be made?

Comment: Andrew, your use of the word 'presentation' is not standard, you should either use standard terminology or explain clearly what you mean.

Comment: @Andrew: unless you specify your involution more concretely, this is still not a good question. The formula $x \mapsto −x$ does not specify an involution of F.

Comment: Sorry for my terminology. I didn't take care of it hoping that if someone is familiar with this then he could help, without digging in details.